# Li polymer cells in parallel

Tags: batteries, lithium-ion

I am using two 3.7V LiPo cells in series to power a device. The output of battery is converted to 12V using a dc-dc converter. I want to increase the capacity so that the device can run longer. Is it possible to used Li batteries in parallel? Because all the battery monitoring ICs I found are designed for cells in series.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to put Li-ion/LiPo cells in parallel, due to their self-balancing nature. Simply make sure that the cells are almost equally charged before connecting them, and then give them a day or so to let them balance.

They can also be charged in parallel, but since the current is distributed among all the cells it will naturally take longer to charge given a specific current; the current can be multiplied by the number of parallel sets to mitigate this.

Comment: Is it safe to do so? And, how do I implement battery fuel gauge in this case?

Comment: It is perfectly safe to do so as long as the cells are all the same model and are within a few millivolts of each other before connecting. If the gauge is voltage-based or uses a relative coulomb counter then there is no need to change anything.